# Set WebSphere variables via command prompt

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am not allowed to use the websphere admin console and I need to set the Websphere variable **`DB2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH`** .
Is there a way so that I can set this variable from the command prompt itself?
version :Websphere 8.5.5.7 ( Network Deployment Edition)

Answer (score 2):

You can use wsadmin + the wsadminlib.py script library from github, it has a function named "setWebSphereVariable" which is pretty straightforward.

https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib

Basics of wsadmin:

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-dist&topic=txml_script